# Как мне передавать и принимать в другой активности переменную stream

Tags: java, android

У меня есть плеер, и мне нужно передавать переменную `url` из списка радиостанций в класс плеера по нажатию `ImageButton`, я вроде разобрался как ее передать, но не знаю как принять.

Answer (score 3):

Я решил свою проблему так:

Класс списка радиостанций:

```
public void station(View view) {
    String url = "url//";
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Player.class);
    intent.putExtra("url", url);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Класс плеера:

onCreate:

```
url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
new PlayerTask().execute(url);
```

Player:

```
class Player extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Boolean>{
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop);
    }
}
```

Ну и `String url;` в начале, надеюсь кому-то будет полезно.